# How to create a generic function with textfield inputs in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a button with a generic function that chooses random elements from an array , checks if the textfield input matches the correct words associated with a particular element from the array then returns true if it does. Please see my code to understand this better

my head is burning trying to make this a generic approach please advise guys.

I just want a button that i can add more cards to the view. Lets say i don't want just variables i want to create another set of instructions with constants or integers

> //MARK: LOGIC
>
> ```
> import Foundation
> import Observation
>
>
> @Observable
> class VariablesViewModel {
>     var textField = ""
>     private var words = ["\"Hello\"","\"Hello \"" ,"\"hello\"", "\" Hello\"", "\"      hello\""]
>     
>     func wordMatch() -> Bool {
>         words.contains(where: textField.contains)
>     }
> }
>
>
>
> //MARK: VIEW 
>
>
> import SwiftUI
>
> struct Variables: View {
>     @State var viewModel = VariablesViewModel()
>     var body: some View {
>         VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 40) {
>           Text("Create a variable called \"greeting\" and assign the value     \"Hello\".")
>                 .font(.title2)
>                 .fontWeight(.semibold)
>             HStack {
>                 Text("1")
>                     .font(.title2)
>                     .foregroundStyle(.gray)
>                 Text("var")
>                     .font(.title2)
>                     .foregroundStyle(.pink)
>                 Text("greeting =")
>                     .font(.title2)
>                 TextField(text: $viewModel.textField ) {
>                     Text("Tap to assign \"Hello\"")
>                         .font(.title2)
>                 }
>                 .font(.title2)
>                 .foregroundStyle(.orange)
>                 if viewModel.wordMatch() {
>                     Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
>                         .imageScale(.large)
>                         .foregroundStyle(.green)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         .alignment(.topLeading)
>     }
> }
> #Preview {
>     Variables()
> }
>
>
> extension View {
>     @ViewBuilder func alignment(_ alignment: Alignment) -> some View {
>         self.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: alignment)
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: what is the purpose of generic here ? text field input is always string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to make the view model generic where you pass both the array values and a matching logic closure at init

```
class VariablesViewModel<Value> {
    var input: Value?
    var matcher: (Value, [Value]) -> Bool
    private var values: [Value]

    init(values: [Value], matcher: @escaping (Value, [Value]) -> Bool) {
        self.matcher = matcher
        self.values = values
    }

    func valueMatch() -> Bool {
        guard let input else { return false }
        return matcher(input, values)
    }
}
```

Examples

```
let viewModel = VariablesViewModel(values: ["Hello","Hello " ,"hello", " Hello", "      hello"]) {
    $1.contains(where: $0.contains)
}

let viewModel2 = VariablesViewModel(values: [1,3,5,7,9]) {
    $1.contains($0)
}
```

Personally I would prefer to pass the value to match rather than having it as a property, in your view it would then be a `@State` property instead than a view model property

```
class VariablesMatcher<Value> {
    var matcher: ([Value], Value) -> Bool
    private var values: [Value]

    init(values: [Value], matcher: @escaping ([Value], Value) -> Bool) {
        self.matcher = matcher
        self.values = values
    }
    func valueMatch(input: Value) -> Bool {
        return matcher(values, input)
    }
}
```

Examples

```
let matcher1 = VariablesMatcher(values: ["Hello","Hello " ,"hello", " Hello", "      hello"]) {
    $0.contains(where: $1.contains)
}
matcher1.valueMatch(input: "Hello")

let matcher2 = VariablesMatcher(values: [1,3,5,7,9]) {
    $0.contains($1)
}
matcher2.valueMatch(input: 3)
```